# Percentage in Case statement

Tags: sql, case, percentage

I have a query below that works but I want to add a column showing the percentage of each of those numbers. Can you help me?

```
select
    count(case when Lunchstatus = 'P'   then 1 else null end) as Paid
  , count(case when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 else null end) as Reduced
  , count(case when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 else null end) as Free
  , count(case when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 else null end) as CertifiedFree
  , count(case when LunchStatus = 'P'   then 1 
               when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 
               when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 
               when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 
               else null 
               end) as Total
from students
where enroll_status = 0 
  and schoolid = %param1%
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would show the ratio, not the percentage.  This is pretty easy:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Lunchstatus = 'P' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Paid, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN LunchStatus = 'R' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Reduced,
       AVG(CASE WHEN LunchStatus = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Free,
       AVG(CASE WHEN LunchStatus = 'FDC' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS CertifiedFree, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN LunchStatus IN ('P', 'FDC', 'R', 'F') THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM students
WHERE ENROLL_STATUS = 0 AND SCHOOLID = %param1%;
```

If you really want a value between 0 and 100, then use `THEN 100.0` rather than `THEN 1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something like this but does not recognize total.

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Lunchstatus = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Paid,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Lunchstatus = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 100.0 / Total,

I can paste the whole COUNT(CASE WHEN LunchStatus = 'P' THEN 1 WHEN LunchStatus = 'FDC' THEN 1 WHEN LUNCHSTATUS = 'R' THEN 1 WHEN LUNCHSTATUS = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) but I was wondering if there's any easier way to do that!? Basically I am trying to get two columns for each number one showing the count and another showing the percentage of that number compared to the total number.